# Playing HD or UHD videos from Youtube or Amazon in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: youtube

I can play HD and UHD movies and videos from Amazon and Youtube in Google Chrome browser in Windows 7.

I can play HD and UHD videos (not movies) from Youtube in Google Chrome browser in Ubuntu.

I cannot play HD and UHD movies from Youtube in Google Chrome browser in Ubuntu. They only play in SD.

I cannot play HD and UHD TV-shows from Amazon in Google Chrome browser in Ubuntu. They only play in SD.

Could anyone please help me and tell me how to fix this so that I can watch HD and UHD movies and videos from Amazon and Youtube in Google Chrome browser in Ubuntu 18.04?

All your help is most appreciated.

Best Regards,
Aby.